# Related questions box show deleted questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, related-questions

Is this a bug or a cache related effect? (Or both?)

Maybe it's only me?

Example: On the Related panel of this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/should-we-rephrase-or-clarify-subjective-and-argumentative) there is currently a "Make it funner" related question that's no longer available.

Comment: We cache the "Related" questions to disk, refreshing them periodically, as it's an expensive operation.  The deleted question would be removed at some point (I think it's no longer there).

Comment: "Some point" meaning after a random amount of activity on that question :)

Comment: @Jarrod - was just about to file this again for this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192827/), which includes the question "How to use several managers and change them by clicking on the link/button in django-admin?" in the related sidebar (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198670/), even though that question was deleted on February 16th. Would it be worth running through lists of related questions every once in a while to purge deleted questions, not necessarily to recalculate the entire list.

Answer (score 8):

It *is* possible for related questions to show a deleted question, as those lists are only rebuilt..

- any time the question or any of its answers are edited
- any time a new answer is provided
- randomly 30% chance of rebuilding triggered by page view, once the question is older than 30 days

Answer (score 4):

Interesting. In the example you give it is fairly recently deleted (yesterday), so it *could* be cache related; but that is pure conjecture...