# Related questions is not updated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, related-questions

30 minutes ago, [anti-patterns](/questions/tagged/anti-patterns) was removed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927371/what-does-debounce-do). Related still contains [What anti-patterns exist for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377999/what-anti-patterns-exist-for-javascript?rq=1) though. I've also conducted a test in the [Sandbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3122/62), which showed the same problem.

[According to Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71506) <sup>Dec '10</sup>, the related questions list is rebuilt when one of the posts is edited, or if a new answer is added. Both criteria are met by the specific question, so I'm wondering why the related question list is still not updated.

Comment: The list is not updated right away. If memory serves, building it is computationally expensive, so we do it periodically rather than all the time. I want to say "daily", but don't quote me on that just yet.

Comment: Looks like the related list is now updated. :)