# What, exactly, triggers rebuilds of the "related" questions sidebar?

Tags: discussion, related-questions

So I find a number of questions that dance around the issue of when the 
related questions sidebar is updated.

- Anna [says it occurs rarely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176001/related-questions-is-not-updated#comment528050_176001) as it is computational intensive
- Jeff [lists a set of conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71506/2509) that include on edits of the question or it's answers.

The thing is, that over on Physics I *re-tagged* [a post from a new user with really abysmal initial tagging](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66964/3d-holograms-like-miku-hatsune-how-do-you-make-such-things), and the sidebar still lists totally unrelated [quantum-mechanics](/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics) related stuff about half an hour later. Then Qmechanic made some content edits.

Are re-tags *not* edits for the purpose of triggering this? Will it get fixed if I just wait a while?

Comment: Random update: 1 hour in and the sidebar just updated very nicely.

Comment: When the cache expires?