# Why was my question closed after being forced into Community Wiki mode?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, community-wiki, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
>   [Why is the stack overflow community so aggressive about question criteria?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26014/why-is-the-stack-overflow-community-so-aggressive-about-question-criteria)

I posted a question that was rather subjective I admit. A moderator converted my question to a community wiki, which is fine. But now the question has been closed as *subjective and argumentative*. Is is not what community wiki questions are for?

See [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298272/how-much-duplicated-code-do-you-tolerate-closed):

Comment: Community Wiki is **not** an escape card to say: I can be subjective and argumentative!

Comment: but all those other subjective threads and "best programmer XXX" are tolerated.  Sure, that's consistent...

Comment: Community Wiki is **not** an escape card to say: I can be subjective and argumentative! -- But it is an escape card to say: I **can** be subjective... but only in indeterminate situations when enough of the community decides that its ok. Simple. :)

Comment: So why do questions like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120/best-programming-books-in-2008 get to stay around?

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512/computer-language-puns-and-jokes
  
it goes on and on.  yet a question with real merit gets closed...

Comment: Yes, tim, we get it, you value consistency.  That's not always possible in a community.  Things sneak by.  That doesn't make them examples of good questions.

Comment: @Michael, I hardly call it sneaking... Jeff has been active on those in the past.  Oh well, Not worth my time.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not what Community Wiki is for, not at all.

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) is what they are for.

Comment: Well, a high reputation user added this comment to my question: "Polls like this should be community wiki"...

Comment: @sly, he was wrong

Comment: @Downvoter I was that high-rep user. The question is programming related and is a poll. There is a long tradition of polls on SO.

Comment: /s/is for/should be for

Comment: @downvoter: the link you provided does not really explain *what* Community Wiki questions are for. It explains *how* a question becomes Community Wiki.

Comment: But the jon skeet trivia and best programmer xxx posts apparently are fine.  Sure, that's consistent.

Comment: @tim, they are not fine for all

Comment: @downvoter.  Yes, I know, and this particular question is actually a lot more relevant than those.

Answer (score 2):

Community Wiki is not for subjective and argumentative questions, it is for the type of questions that have the need to be edited by many users at different levels.  The users who always post something along the lines of "Make this question community wiki", are subverting the intention of the CW device.

And for the record, that question wasn't a poll, it was just a vague, subjective question.

Comment: CW is for whatever the majority of active users say it is.

Comment: @Neil: you're in the minority here.

Comment: @John How do you know? And "here" is not SO.

Comment: @Neil: the question was about SO, and if you're not actually in the minority (which recollection suggests you are), then you _should_ be. You seem to want SO to devolve into a discussion forum.

Comment: @John I haven't kept my views on the general quality of SO questions quiet, so I'm surprised you think that's what I want. I believe that SO should be about answering technical questions, which this one was. And what are you "recalling"?

Comment: It doesn't matter what any of us *wants*, or thinks CW *should* be: CW **is** frequently used as a way to mollify users who think folks shouldn't be getting rep for subjective discussions. It's been that way for almost as long as SO has been active, and unlikely to change regardless of what the consensus might be *here*. And given that Atwood and the moderators have been willing to force-CW subjective questions in cases where they've been unwilling to force-close (even making this behavior automatic for questions with > *n* answers), it's not unreasonable to believe that this is intended...

Comment: @Neil: I'm recalling the fact that you don't seem to get the distinction between a Q&A site and a discussion forum.

Comment: @Shog9: I do wish they'd add a separate, moderator-set flag for "permitted discussion". I think "requires edits from many people" is something that the community should set; I think "this is a discussion but we want to permit it just the same" is something that moderators should set.

Comment: @Neil, CW is defined in the FAQ, it shouldn't be used as a weapon.

Answer (score 2):

There's something of a tradition on SO of [using CW for polls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14308/should-poll-questions-be-community-wiki): questions with a finite number of answers where users are expected to vote up the existing answers rather than posting duplicates, edit in additional information where appropriate, etc.

*Examples*: [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c), [C++ Urban Myths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245196/c-urban-myths)

Another sort of question that's frequently seen on SO (and also often marked Community Wiki) is the "What do you think?" question. These aren't so much *polls* as they are *discussion threads*: the phrasing of the question invites each reader to share his own personal experiences and opinions, and discussion frequently thrives in the comments as well. While you will find many of these on SO (indeed, this category includes most of the most popular questions on the site), they tend to be more readily closed, as they have little to offer casual readers beyond opinionated arguments.

*Examples*: [What is the worst programming language you ever worked with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961942/what-is-the-worst-programming-language-you-ever-worked-with), [What are the worst working conditions you have written code in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741581/what-are-the-worst-working-conditions-you-have-written-code-in)

As should be clear from the examples, the deciding factor is public opinion<sup>1</sup>, not any set of concrete rules: **if enough people like your question, it'll either stay open or get re-opened**; otherwise, it'll be closed and eventually deleted. No one person<sup>2</sup> can say for sure which outcome will befall an individual question...

---

<sup>1<sub>Ok, so if a single moderator likes it then they can keep it open, and if a single moderator hates it, then they can delete it outright... but those tend to be edge cases.</sub></sup>
<sup>2<sub>apart from moderators</sub>1</sup>

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: It's a good question (and has attracted some good answers), and -- while it's indeed somewhat subjective -- it's not argumentative or confrontational. This question definitely has a place on SO and should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I may as well throw in my 2 cents. I think that the S&A reason for closing (which was why the question was closed) should only be used for questions like "Why does Java suck?" and in fact I rarely close questions for the S&A reason. The question should not have been closed for any other reason (OK, I'm sure there's a dupe somewhere, but I can't find it), it was a poll, so it should have been CW.

Comment: @Neil: I would argue that we need a new close reason, "This is a discussion question, but this is a Q&A site". There are many questions I'd prefer to close with that reason, as they are not actually causing unpleasant arguments. The question being referred to is one of them.

Comment: "Not a real question" works for me... Had the author bothered to sketch out a more specific scenario it would *still* have been subjective, but somewhat less argumentative - right now, the answers seem more inclined towards platitudes ("keep code understandable", "rule of three") because in generalizing his question, Sly made it almost impossible to disagree with his own assertion ("Yes, I follow DRY religiously, even when it makes the code unreadable!")

Comment: @Shog9: I'd like to distinguish between questions which, as written, do not have an answer, and questions which have an infinite number of answers (IOW, discussions). I think that would make it easier to say, "this question is inappropriate for a Q&A site because it requires a discussion". It would also make it clearer who thinks discussions are appropriate for SO/SU/SF.

Comment: @John: I'd like a waffle. ;-)
(see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19260/split-subjective-and-argumentative-close-reason)

Comment: +1 questions with Technical content are certainly more in line with what I think SO is - rather than nonsense like the "best programmer XXX" and jon skeet facts that are tolerated.

Comment: @Shog9: I've started on your waffle: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40159/requesting-new-close-reason-discussion

Comment: @tim: they can have all the technical content they want. But if they're discussions, then they belong on a different site. BTW, I would have voted down "Jon Skeet Facts", but at this late date, it's pointless.

Comment: @John Saunders - one can say the same thing about other questions here - and this one in particular is relevant to programmers.  It certainly has a lot more value than many other questions on SO.

Comment: @tim: it doesn't matter. It's been decided by the creators that this is not the sort of question they want on SO. A significant portion of the benefit we get from SO as opposed to other types of web site is precisely the fact that it consists of Questions and Answers, and not Discussions. Permitting Discussions on SO would make it a much less effective way to get Answers to our Questions.

Comment: @John -= My understanding (and the literal post from Jeff) was that this site is for and run by the community.  NOT JEFF.  And how is the jon skeet crap and other stuff that Jeff also posted to in the spirit that you mention?  It is inconsistent.  Jeff's actions contradict your statement.

Comment: @Tim: I'd vote those off as well. I think they come under "occasional fun". You seem to be talking about something different - a question that starts off as a discussion, and ends there. I think those are great questions for some other site.

Comment: @John, OK, at least you are consistent - some people try to quite jeff here as the answer, but jeff participates in the nonsense and joke stuff - but only the ones he deems appropriate - so there is no real hard definition of what belongs and what doesn't.  All this talk without consistency is nonsense

Comment: @tim: "All this talk without consistency is nonsense", except for me.

Comment: @John, I don't understand.  Are you saying I am being inconsistent?

Comment: @tim: no, don't worry about it. I misread your statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons a Community Wiki question can be closed for:

- exact duplicate
- not programming related
- subjective and argumentative
- not a real question
- too localized
- belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com
- belongs on serverfault.com
- belongs on superuser.com

When it comes to the validity of questions, the standard rules apply to Community Wiki questions. Personally, I flag my questions or answers CW when even though they satisfy these requirements, I don't want  to receive reputation points for them for some reason or other.

I don't think that CW ever served its original purpose; I really doubt that that many low-reputation users edited CW questions or answers.

Comment: +1 for your last sentence. I've never seen any more editing done to CW posts compared to normal posts (with the exception perhaps of things like the faqs on meta). CW has long since become the flag for subjective posts to prevent users getting cheesy rep boosts. While the whole wiki concept as described by the faq (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) is nice in concept, the simple (sad?) fact is that it hasn't been picked up that way by the community.

Comment: It seems to me that people are reluctant to edit what other people have written, and new users are probably even more reluctant.