# Please, help me understand why is this question non constructive

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, not-constructive

This is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480920/document-db-for-windows-xp-32-bits).
Why is it non constructive?
I found the two answers very constructive and was evaluating both.

Comment: If you think the question was closed wrongly you can vote to reopen it.

Comment: There seems to be a new site in beta (not Stack Exchange related) that caters to these types of questions: [Slant.co](http://slant.co).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker nice site! Now implement a migration path to it as close reason :)

Comment: your confusion indicates a known issue with closure reasons, see more details on that in: [Help us make “Not Constructive” and “Not a Real Question” closures more effective](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171732/165773)

Answer (score 16):

It is a [shopping question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Now, shopping questions are considered unsuitable for Stack Overflow (and generally the Stack Exchange network), for the reasons outlined in the blog I have linked.

The naming of the close reason is not as good as it can be - think of it more as "not suitable for this site" than "not constructive".

Comment: I'm partial to `not a good fit` as well. `not constructive` just sounds so... dismissive.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I knew [that sounded familiar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165789/should-not-constructive-be-replaced-by-open-ended). ;)

Comment: What is wrong with a shopping question? We do shopping all the time having to choose between a gazillion technologies doing the same thing  with a gazillion compromises. Should I try all the options I can think of and then ask particular questions on each of them? I will be fired by the time I am done.

Comment: @mark - This style of question is not suitable to the Stack Exchange sites. Did you read the blog?

Comment: Yes, I did and I agree only partially. I found the answers to my question rather concrete and very useful. Others might too. Closing a question without considering the usefulness of the answers does not sound like a very good practice.

Comment: @mark You know, people developed software before Stack Overflow, and we weren't really getting fired for evaluating technologies... If you can't do it on your own, perhaps getting fired isn't the biggest of your problems. /get off my lawn

Comment: @Yannis - I am not that talented as others. To evaluate MongoDB, CouchDB, CouchBase, OrientDB, ArangoDB, Cassandra, HsqlDb with hacks to simulate schemaless and come up with useful recommendations will likely take me much more time than I will be given. Others probably do it faster. Alas, we were not all created equal...

Comment: @mark A quick look at your profile is proof enough that you are more talented than you seem to think.

Comment: My car is broken and I need it to get to work. Why can't I ask how to fix a coolant? I'll be fired if I can't get it working. It would surely be useful to others too.

Comment: @Juhana- I am sure there is a site for car mechanics where you should be able to ask exactly this question.

Comment: And I'm sure there's a site where you can ask for tech recommendations...

Comment: And why not SO? People give tech recommendations in replies to every second question, even though most of the questions do not ask for them.

Comment: @mark - Because answers to these questions get stale. Because the answers to these questions are subjective.

Comment: I was under the impression that "shopping questions" were OK providing you included specific details about exactly what you wanted. This helps it avoid becoming a huge list of everyone's favorite X, with no way to tell a "correct" answer from an "incorrect" one. The question appears to provide some fairly specific details, so I think it's OK

Comment: @Oded - there will be stale answers. There will be wrong answers. How many times have you come across a question with the accepted answer being credited lower than some other answer and the comments to which explain that the accepted answer is wrong? The accepted answer might have been right at the time and then became stale and wrong. I have come across one such question recently. Too bad I did not bookmark it. The point is stale and wrong answers are part of SO as well as excellent and up-to-date answers. The reader should consult the date of the question, something I always do.

Comment: @mark: you've mistaken this network for a forum. There are a number of wonderful forums out there which will gladly accept your discussions of the best products.

Comment: This comment thread should be closed as non constructive.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, it takes an opinion to answer that question. You're going to get a bunch of different answers in which you'd have to choose, some equally as good as others.

Comment: And how is it different from a pure programming questions? That they have a clear cut answer? Please...

Comment: @mark The focus on clear cut answers is what distinguishes SO from most other sites, so I'd say it is worth protecting. The idea of running a sister network for opinion-based discussions is not bad, though. Like DocSalvage 's suggestion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732

Comment: My comment about the clear cut answer was misunderstood. I am developing software long enough to learn that there is no such thing as a clear cut answer, but for most trivial questions.